# Why do allophane soils behave as gels?

Tags: minerals, soil-science

It is notoriously difficult to determine the texture of soil containing allophane and immogolite. According to the literature this is because the clay fraction "behaves as a gel", i.e. it's not possible to disperse the particles from each other. But why? What actually happens? Somebody who knows, or who has a reference to where it is explained?